# Most efficient way of aquiring gold

Tags: clicker-heroes

I've found the following 2 strategies for making money:

1. Idle on the highest level where you can defeat an enemy nearly instantaneously
2. Idle on the highest boss you have access to

For my game so far, this usually boils down to a choice between [boss level] or [boss level - 1].  Is it faster to make money by killing smaller creatures faster, or by repeatedly tackling the bosses?

Comment: This is going to take some real looking into. I have done comparisons between [Boss Level] and [Boss Level +4] and Boss Level always seemed to win out over a 60s time frame (What the game tracks for you) but it seems to vary greatly between which levels you are testing. 15 and 19, 15 won hands down. The margin was very narrow between 20 and 24 however.. So I do not feel confident enough in my knowledge to answer this yet... but I do hope this alternate to your question above helps give a better answer.

Comment: It would be nice to have a late-game answer for this question.  Often it gets to the point where defeating the highest level non-boss takes what seems to be an hour or two without clicking, With the chest bonus I have trouble telling if it's actually better than popping lower-level monsters constantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check gold reward vs mobs HP at:

- http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Levels

If you divide money by HP you get how costly money reward for spent damage. In early games this ratio - `0.066` and this value grows with level. *Seems that data wikia data outdated*.

People at wikia recommend **grind on latest available level as ratio increased** at current v0.14.

That true as [reversed formula for gold v0.14/v0.15](http://www.reddit.com/r/ClickerHeroes/comments/2hsxrf/collection_of_game_formulae_and_misc_information/):

```
MonsterHP/15*min(3,1.025^max(0,Level-75))
```

So up to level 75 - there are no difference (except mob respawn time penalty) - `1/15`, after that multiplier increased up to 120 lvl and become `3` and no more changed.

Some say that on level `boss+1`, `boss+2` ration lesser then on `boss-1`, `boss-2` but seems that no longer true.

Decompiling old version of game [show formula](http://www.reddit.com/r/ClickerHeroes/comments/2ds8tt/accurate_level_hp_gold_gold_per_second_best_farm/) where gold in linear dependency on mob heals which is no longer true.

Also offline gold calculation (when you open game from idle) take in account **latest opened level** and this currently take the best value.

*As game in alpha stage - all may change tomorrow*.

Also note that mob respawn take 0.5-0.7 sec. So it is **better beat long lived huge HP mobs** then most of the time spend on waiting respawn ))

Also take in account that after your first ascension, you unlock "Progression mode" which **automatically moves you up until you fail to defeat a boss**, after which it puts you back down one level and turns off progression mode.

Comment: I find that with a higher chance of treasure chests and a multiplier on their contents, I can get a better result over 60s about 15 levels below the highest non-boss level *if* that highest non-boss level takes more than 10 seconds per monster. But once you can beat a boss to progress it's for the best.